# How to split values at multiple points in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is an assignment for school I have a text file with the following data:

```
8/28/2018|26064.01953
8/29/2018|26124.57031
8/30/2018|25986.91992
8/31/2018|25964.82031
9/4/2018|25952.48047
9/5/2018|25974.99023
9/6/2018|25995.86914
```

There are many entries all on a single line in this format. My assignment is to Create an application that imports the text file and completes the following operations for display to the user.

- Average close value for the entire year.
- Average close value per month
- Highest close value and the date in which that happened.
- Lowest close value and the date of which that happened.
- Sort prices lowest to highest and write the sorted list to a new text file called `DJI_Sorted`.

```
def main ():
    infile = open('DJI.txt', 'r')
    values = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    values = (values.strip() for value in values.split("|") for value in values.split("/"))
    print(values) 
main()
```

Upon running this code I get the following error:

```
<generator object main.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x028F90B0>
```

I am trying to split `8/28/2018|26064.01953` into a list with `8/28/2018` and `23031.0193` so statistics and calculations can be done on the values. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's not an error - it's a representation of a generator object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't seem to be an error, it is a python Repr (representation).

The cause is that you are using a generator expression. Printing a generator expression prints out the generator's repr, not the values.

Change

```py
values = (values.strip() for value in values.split("|") for value in values.split("/"))
```

to

```py
values = [values.strip() for value in values.split("|") for value in values.split("/")]
```

However, that doesn't seem to split as you would want it to.  I recommend simplifying and doing it in two steps. First split the values on the space (" ") to get a list of individual values. Then split on the "|" to get a list of lists with the inner list being date/value pairs.

```py
    values=values.split(" ")
    values=[value.split("|") for value in values]
```